# Phonegap Android app displays only themeroller

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, github-for-windows, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I am in desperate need of answers!!

I have packaged my app with Phonegap via Github.

After loading, I go to test using qr code on an Android device, and it only display the Themeroller file!!!

Here is the repository link: [GitHub](https://github.com/JessicaClark/Meltdown-Release)

Here is the PhoneGap link: [PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1280362/builds)

Not sure if this matters, but it is the debug version, and is hydrated...

Someone please help!!!!!!
Any feedback, a tutorial, anything would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was having the themeroller file (index) commited to my GitHub. Once I removed that file, it worked fine!